# Showing and hiding a fixed element on pre-defined screen widths

Tags: html, css

I want to hide my element on `@media(min-width:576px)` and want to show my element on `@media(min-width: 768px)` as I need to use `display: fixed;` for my element, but the `display: fixed;` element is not showing my element.

```
@media (min-width : 576px) {
    #content-item { display: none;}
}
@media (min-width : 768px) {
    #content-item { display: fixed;}
}
```

I expect to show my #content-item element and also want to use display: fixed; property

Comment: Display fixed not exist. You have to use fixed in position not in display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making a confusion between display and position.
try this.

```
@media (min-width : 576px) {
    #content-item { display: none;}
}
@media (min-width : 768px) {
    #content-item { 
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
    }
}
```